# helm-projectile-ag use thing-at-point as input?

Tags: helm, projectile, helm-projectile, ag

I want to use the current word as the input when I do `helm-projectile-ag`. That saves me the typing work. I didn't see this option in `customize`.

How would I implement that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it. The setting is

```
(setq helm-ag-insert-at-point 'symbol)
```

Reference: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/1848#issuecomment-108973505

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the `helm-ag-insert-at-point` is only applicable to `helm-ag`, not `helm-projectile-ag`.

I think you should use following elisp snippet:
https://github.com/ageldama/configs/blob/master/emacs/dot-emacs-2018#L252

```
(defun my-helm-projectile-rg--region-selection (old-fn &rest arguments)
  (let ((thing (thing-at-point 'symbol)))
    (if (null thing)
        (apply old-fn arguments)
      thing)))

(advice-add #'helm-projectile-rg--region-selection
            :around #'my-helm-projectile-rg--region-selection)
```

Comment: This is not necessary, `(setq helm-ag-insert-at-point 'symbol)` works for `helm-projectile-ag`

Comment: To back up the first comment. This is not true - 'symbol works just fine. You should edit or remove your reply.